# Is there a way to do this...R.Id."string"?

Tags: android

I have a folder called "raw" in my Res folder with a selection of short audio tracks and the screen displays several buttons.

I would like to be able to start the MediaPlayer like this...

```
String[] track = {"track1", "track2", "track3", etc...}

mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.track[x]);
```

The issue is with the `R.raw.track[x]`.

Is there a way to do this in the way I'm attempting or do I need a whole new approach?

Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume here that your `x` is an index, perhaps pulled from a user selection from `track`.

You have two main options:

1. Have a corresponding `int[] {R.raw.track1, R.raw.track2, ...}` and look up the `R.raw` value that way
2. [Use `getResources().getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to look up an identifier at runtime

The second option is easier but uses reflection and so is not super-quick. In your case, that should not matter, as I doubt that you are looking up these IDs in a tight loop.